# WebChromeClient.FileChooserParams of onShowFileChooser cannot be resolved to a type

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I overwrote the method `onShowFileChooser (WebView, ValueCallback, WebChromeClient.FileChooserParams)` in the `setWebChromeClient()` of my activity, which implements a `WebView`, but eclipse gives me the "cannot be resolved to a type" error on the `WebChromeClient.FileChooserParams` parameter.
How can I fix it?

```
myWebView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {
        public void openFileChooser(ValueCallback<Uri> filePathCallback) {
            mFilePathCallback4 = filePathCallback;
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
            intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
            intent.setType("*/*");
            startActivityForResult(
                    Intent.createChooser(intent, "File Chooser"),
                    REQUEST_FILE_PICKER);
        }

        public void openFileChooser(ValueCallback filePathCallback,
                String acceptType) {
            mFilePathCallback4 = filePathCallback;
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
            intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
            intent.setType("*/*");
            startActivityForResult(
                    Intent.createChooser(intent, "File Chooser"),
                    REQUEST_FILE_PICKER);
        }

        public void openFileChooser(ValueCallback<Uri> filePathCallback,
                String acceptType, String capture) {
            mFilePathCallback4 = filePathCallback;
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
            intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
            intent.setType("*/*");
            startActivityForResult(
                    Intent.createChooser(intent, "File Chooser"),
                    REQUEST_FILE_PICKER);
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onShowFileChooser(WebView webView,
                ValueCallback<Uri[]> filePathCallback,
                WebChromeClient.FileChooserParams fileChooserParams) {
            mFilePathCallback5 = filePathCallback;
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
            intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
            intent.setType("*/*");
            startActivityForResult(
                    Intent.createChooser(intent, "File Chooser"),
                    REQUEST_FILE_PICKER);
            return true;
        }

        public void onProgressChanged(WebView view, int progress) {
            // Make the bar disappear after URL is loaded, and changes
            // string to Loading...
            MyActivity.setTitle("Loading...");
            MyActivity.setProgress(progress * 100); // Make the bar
                                                    // disappear after URL
                                                    // is loaded

            // Return the app name after finish loading
            if (progress == 100)
                MyActivity.setTitle(R.string.app_name);
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try updating your SDK to Android 5.0.